# How to Monitor camel route using jboss operational network?

Tags: routes, monitoring, rhq

I am new to `SERVICEMIX` and `JBoss Operations Network`(JON).

I have configured `JON` server and agent, service mix sucessfully.

But How do I monitor `camel routes` in `JON`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a plugin for JBoss ON, that allows for monitoring of the routes. I think this may be available in the future (dec 2012/jan 2013 -- with some luck).

For the moment the best bet is to use the [generic JMX plugin](http://management-platform.blogspot.de/2008/11/monitoring-custom-jmx-mbeans-with-jopr.html) of RHQ / JBoss ON and to monitor those via Jmx. See also [this link](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/managing-camel-routes-with-jmx-apis.html).